# Multiplication table in Python with # on all even numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a python multiplication table from 2 - 10. If you enter an invalid number it will tell you that it is an invalid entry and ask you to input a number again. It is also supposed to put a # on all even numbers. I am having trouble continuing after an invalid entry and also putting a # on all even numbers. My current code is below

```
def main():
rows = int(input("What size multiplication table would you like (2-10): "))
if rows <=1 or rows >10:
    print (" Invalid Entry - Enter a number between 2 - 10 ")
else:
    counter = 0
    multiplicationTable(rows,counter)
def multiplicationTable(rows,counter):
size = rows + 1
for i in range (1,size):
    for nums in range (1,size):
        value = i*nums
        print(value,sep=' ',end="\t")
        counter += 1
        if counter%rows == 0:
            print()
        else:
            counter
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this on my phone so bear with me.
Since you are trying to only get a certain input, you want to have a loop so that we can keep asking the user to enter a number if it is outside the range we want.

So in a generic example where we repeatedly ask a user for a certain input:

```
While True:
     rows = int(input(“enter size: “))
     if 1 <= rows < 10: 
         multiplicationTable(rows, 0)
         break
     else:
         print(“Invalid”)
         continue
```

`While True:` will run infinitely naturally. However, the magic is in the `continue` and `break` statements. `continue` will make it restart at the top of the loop and `break` will make it exit the loop after the process is done.

**note:**
Some programmers consider it bad practice to use the loops in this fashion because it could imply poor logic.

If you need help with an alternate solution I can try and help when I get to my computer. 
Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, That was very helpful and with your guidance and a little tweaking on my end, I was able to restart the loop with an invalid entry. Now the last part I am having an issue with is have each positive number show a # sign after the number. For example, when the program runs it would show 5 10# 15 20# 25 30# or 1 2# 3 4# 5 6#

Comment: So that will be an easy fix. Notice that you are going to need to alter the what is being printed out to console when the number is even. Since my professor always stresses this in class, I will give you a nudge: you will need to use an if statement that checks if `value` is even with some mathematical operator. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thank you again for the advice. I finally was able to get it to work properly

def multiplicationTable(rows,counter):
    size = rows + 1
    for i in range (1,size):
        for nums in range (1,size):
            value = i*nums
            if(value%2)==0:
                print(value,sep=' ',end="#""\t")
            else:
                print(value,sep=' ',end="\t")      
                  
            counter += 1
            if counter%rows == 0:
                print()
            else:
                counter